# why and when is a double-pointer required?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have been a sysadmin most of my life, but recently decided to practice some my dev knowledge and attempt a devops position. I have as such been practicing some C and Python skills and wrote some code for inserting a number into a linked list.

```
void list_insert(struct list *h, int d)
{
        struct list *elem = malloc(sizeof(struct list));

        elem->data = d;
        elem->next = NULL;

        if (!h) {
                h = elem;
        } else {
                elem->next = h;
                h = elem;
        }
}
```

I noticed that this function doesn't seem to alter the outside view of the variable h (i.e whatever is passed to list_insert) and I noticed that printing at the end of the insert function seems to work. So having tried to look for answers online, I couldn't find anything, obvious but I found most list implementations would have double-pointers. I changed my function to use double-pointers and then it suddenly started working. Could someone help me understand what's happening here as I know pointer management is an important concept and I think I understand what a pointer is and how it relates to memory, but I don't think I get why a single pointer does not get changed, whereas a double-pointer does.

Thanks!

Comment: when you pass a parameter to a function, the parameter gets copied and the function works with a copy of the original. When you pass a pointer (the pointer=int is copied) and you do *pointer=something, you modify the data where the pointer points to, "allowing you to see the changes outside the function". thus, var * * would be a writable pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, arguments to function are passed by values. Even pointers are passed by values.

For example:

```
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int allocatingMemory(int* ptr)
{
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;
}// We are not returning the pointer to allocated memory

int main(void)
{
    int* ptr;
    int allocated = allocatingMemory(ptr);
    if(allocated == 0)
    {
        *ptr = 999;// Boom!!! 
        free(ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To overcome this issue, we use

```
int allocatingMemory(int** ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(*ptr == NULL)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int* ptr;
    int isAllocated = allocatingMemory(&ptr);
    if(isAllocated == 0)
    {
        *ptr = 999;
        free(ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you are working with `linked list`s and say for example, you want to modify the head. You will pass a `pointer to pointer` (Note that, it is not called as double pointer) to `head node`.

Comment: Thank you! Some clarification required, What does it mean when a pointer is passed by value?

Comment: As variables are passed by value to functions. This means variable value is getting copied to an argument in the function parameter list. Similarly, pointers are also passed by value. This means, pointer value (pointer has address of some memory location) gets copied (address is getting copied) to another pointer in the function argument list. They call this as pass by address.

Answer (score 4):

To change memory in the caller's context, a function needs to have a pointer to that memory.

If the caller of your function has an empty list in a variable, and does an insert on that list like so:

```
struct list *numbers = NULL;

list_insert(numbers, 4711);
```

then of course inside `list_insert()` all we have is the NULL pointer, so we can't change the value of the variable `numbers` in the caller's context.

If, on the other hand, we're given a pointer to the variable, we can change the variable.

That said, it's much cleaner (in my opinion) to *return* the new head of the list, i.e. make the function's signature be `struct list * list_insert(struct list *head, int x);`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting "return the new head of the list". Makes it much more readable.

Comment: I would prefere best of both worlds, so to return the value AND use a reference. In that case you can use the function as a parameter to another function AND you have the head for later disposal.

Comment: thank you unwind. If I could upvote your answer, I would. Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question :)

How would you then use it.

h = list_insert(h, 1) for example?

Answer (score 1):

h is actually a copy of the original pointer, so your original pointer doesnot get modified. That is why you should use a double pointer.

There are numerous questions related to that on SO. for example [Using single versus double pointers in Linked lists implemented in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10043327/2598660)