# What's the advantage of two-level pointer used in double linked list in c language?

Tags: c, pointers, nginx

Every worker process in nginx has a posted event queue. the ngx_event_t has two pointers, next and prev:

```
/* the links of the posted queue */
ngx_event_t *next;
ngx_event_t **prev;
```

the nginx use these two pointers to implement posted event queue, the next point to next event  and the prev point to the previous event's next pointer. 
The post operation:

```
ev->next = (ngx_event_t *) *queue;  
ev->prev = (ngx_event_t **) queue;        
*queue = ev;                   
if (ev->next) {                                                       
    ev->next->prev = &ev->next;                                      
}
```

The delete operation:

```
*(ev->prev) = ev->next;  
if (ev->next) {              
    ev->next->prev = ev->prev;
}
```

Why does prev use two-level pointer type? what's the advantage?

Comment: This will give a good site idea on why to use double pointers not only in linked list, other places also... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20281858/1814023

Answer (score 0):

The level of a pointer depending up on how you are accessing the memory address stored in a pointer variable. If you are de referencing it from a pointer then you need single pointer. If you are dereferencing it from pointer to pointer then you need double pointer, and so on. In your case you are dereferencing it from pointer to pointer that's why you need double pointer there.